# The Rambam on health

Tags: rambam, health-safety-shmira

Does the Rambam talk about health in his *Sefer* , *Mishnah Torah*  ? I'm thinking maybe he talks about it in *Hilchos דעות*.

Comment: What about "health" are you looking for? How to stay healthy? What sins affect one's health? What value is there in maintaining health? How to affect other's health? Conjugation of the word "health"? Please [edit] to clarify what you want so we can best assist you in finding that.

Comment: It should be remembered that people should first and foremost rely on the most up to date medical information.

Answer (score 5):

In [Hilkhoth De'oth chapter 4](http://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah,_Human_Dispositions.4.1?lang=he-en&layout=heLeft&sidebarLang=all), the Rambam lists practices that he recommends as healthy:

> הואיל והיות הגוף בריא ושלם מדרכי השם הוא שהרי אי אפשר שיבין או ידע דבר מידיעת הבורא והוא חולה לפיכך צריך להרחיק אדם עצמו מדברים המאבדין את הגוף ולהנהיג עצמו בדברים המברין והמחלימים ואלו הן
>
> Since a healthy and whole body is necessary for the ways of G-D (for it is impossible to imply or know anything of Godly wisdom when one is sick), therefore one must distance himself from things that are damaging to the body and to accustom oneself to things that strengthen and make one healthy. They are as follows...

Also, the Rambam in [Hilchoth Rotzeach 11:4](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A8%D7%9E%D7%91%22%D7%9D_%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A6%D7%97_%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%AA_%D7%A0%D7%A4%D7%A9_%D7%99%D7%90_%D7%93) is often invoked regarding maintaining one's health:

> וכן כל מכשול שיש בו סכנת נפשות מצות עשה להסירו ולהשמר ממנו ולהזהר בדבר יפה יפה. שנאמר השמר לך ושמור נפשך. ואם לא הסיר והניח המכשולות המביאין לידי סכנה ביטל מצות עשה ועבר בלא תשים דמים.
>
> ...and so too with regard to any snare that involves a risk to life, there is a positive commandment to remove it and to be very very careful in this regard, as it says in the verse "be careful with yourself and watch your soul". And if he did not remove it and left snares that lead to risks to life, he nullified a positive commandment and violated "Place ye not blood..."

See also the [Tzitz Eliezer  15:39](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14514&pgnum=110) (cited [here](http://www.etzion.org.il/vbm/archive/yomyom/dafyomyomi/2012-11-04.php)) who invokes this Rambam with regard to smoking.